# I am creating a web-based sysadmin portal for monitoring my web server

Tags: sql-server-2005, iis, coldfusion, monitoring

This will involve monitoring, coldfusion, sql server 2005, iis, coldfusion errors, hardware.

For example, I want to create graphical easy to understand charts showing coldfusion performance, but I want to know what data can i access underneath the system to get that?

Are there any resources for that?

Yes I know there is a balance from getting too much information that can affect server performance, and i hope to avoid that, but get essential limited info that can help us keep an eye on the server..

What kinds of things would you watch, and what ways are there to monitor them?

Yes, I know there are good server monitor tools for coldfusion, but we can't afford them. So we have to roll our own..

Thank You for your time..

Comment: "but we can't afford them. So we have to roll our own" - and how much is the time you spend re-creating the wheel going to cost you?

Comment: It would take a lot more time trying to convince anyone of the need for this, and the value of it's cost. Just makes more sense to do a more limited, simple version. And then let that show the value.

Comment: any other ideas or solutions, other than telling me to not roll my own?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at **[cfTracker](http://github.com/misterdai/cfTracker)** - and if it doesn't do what you want, maybe talk to [David](http://misterdai.wordpress.com/) about helping to improve that project, instead of starting from scratch on another.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking out Ray Camden's Article called Server Monitor API In Coldfusion 8 http://archive.networknewz.com/networknewz-10-20070625ServerMonitorAPIinColdfusion8.html

Answer (score 1):

User GetMetricData for monitoring your application in your CFML page. It's useful for only single-server installation.

Following coding is to GetMetricDate and Cfchart.

> <cfset pmData =
>   GetMetricData(“PERF_MONITOR") >
>
> <cfchart chartheight="500"
>   chartwidth="700" format="PNG"
>   showlegend="yes">
>
> <cfchartseries type="bar"
>   seriescolor="##639526"
>   paintstyle="light"
>   colorlist="##ff8080,##ffff80,##80ff80,##0080ff,##ff80c0,##ff80ff,##ff8040,##008000,##0080c0,##808000">
>
> <cfchartdata item="Page Hits"
>   value="#pmData.PageHits#">
>
> <cfchartdata item="Request Queued"
>   value="#pmData.ReqQueued#">
>
> <cfchartdata item="Database Hits"
>   value="#pmData.DBHits#">
>
> <cfchartdata item="Request Running"
>   value="#pmData.ReqRunning#">
>
> <cfchartdata item="Request
>   TimedOut"
>   value="#pmData.ReqTimedOut#">
>
> <cfchartdata item="Bytes In"
>   value="#pmData.BytesIn#">
>
> <cfchartdata item="Bytes Out"
>   value="#pmData.BytesOut#">
>
> <cfchartdata item="Avg Queue Time"
>   value="#pmData.AvgQueueTime#">
>
> <cfchartdata item="Avg Request
>   Time" value="#pmData.AvgReqTime#">
>
> <cfchartdata item="Avg Database
>   Time" value="#pmData.AvgDBTime#">
>
> </cfchartseries>
>
> </cfchart>

Comment: very interesting and i like it. Also been playing with webcharts3d, and using ajax to update gauge dashboards...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do to get performance info from CF for some simple graphs, and since your on a Windows platform you can use [perfmon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645516(VS.71).aspx) - the built-in Windows performance metrics gathering tool.

First you allow performance monitoring in CF Admin.

Then you can then set up a few *perfmon* tasks (using Reliability and Performance Monitoring tool under Administrative Tools) on the server. These can access ColdFusion Server metrics such as average request time, hits/sec etc. as well as standard Windows metrics such as memory used and CPU utilization.

It's all for free and if you write the results to a csv file, you can parse that every few minutes into a database table.

Once you have that you can use native CF processing such as `<cfgraph>` to graph the CF server performance.

I can also tell you that this *perfmon* approach will have a negligible affect on server performance.

I hope that helps.